# Visual Studio does not access files, no matter r, \\,/, absolute or relative path

Tags: visual-studio, file, path, cd

Visual Studio does not access files when running code, no matter if using absolute or relative path, raw or not, using double \ or just / or even files online.

Terminal shows:

```
PS C:\Users\...> cd "c:/Users/..."
PS C:\Users\...> & "c:/Users/.../.venv/Scripts/python.exe" "c:/Users/.../code.py"
```

It must be something elementary I am missing, but I cannot solve it.
The location of the file or settings of Visual Studio for terminal execution (dir of file, etc.) did not change anything.

Thank you.

I tried without success:

- using absolute or relative path, raw string or not, using / or double \ or even path on the web,
- adjusting python extension settings regarding terminal execution directory,
- changing the location of the files (same folder as project or not),
  different environments
- simple code or using libraries to open the file
- simple image files or pretrained CNN models

Nothing changed.